# Meaning of slang term "sin convis"

Tags: coloquialismos, perú

I have seen this term used in a printed book and online in a few places and the best I can come up with from context (as I haven't yet found it explained anywhere) is like "don't ask me to share" or "I am not sharing", but I'm not quite sure. It could be something similar to "I know it's bad, but no regrets".

Not sure if **con convis** or just **convis** make any sense. I am guessing it comes from the verb **convidar** but is not a regular conjugation.

Any more concrete ideas on what this is supposed to mean and if it is a Peruvian thing or is more general?

Excerpt from the play *[Un misterio, una pasión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Un_misterio,_una_pasi%C3%B3n)* by Aldo Miyashiro

[image: Dialogue with "sin convis"]

You can find other examples in [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/postresdelperu/photos/sin-convis-/1487570624682639/), [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23sinconvis&src=typd) (see below) and some online forums.

[image: Tweet]

Comment: I did notice something online about "con convis o sin convis."

Comment: What's the title of the book? Is Aldo Miyashiro the author? Could you capture one of the tweets? I think that one of your guesses is right, it seems to mean: I'm not sharing. And probably is a Peruvian thing but every region/province/city/whatever may have a different coloquial expression for that in the Hispanic world. I think that that one is not generally used, at least in Spain.

Comment: Yes, Aldo Miyashiro is the author, it comes from the book version of this: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Un_misterio,_una_pasi%C3%B3n A public FB post: https://www.facebook.com/postresdelperu/photos/sin-convis-/1487570624682639/  A forum post: https://www.forosperu.net/temas/porque-la-vida-es-mas-trabajo-dolor-sufrimiento-lucha-que-satisfaciones.642885/  Several examples that use the #sinconvis hashtag on twitter: https://twitter.com/search?q=%23sinconvis&src=typd

Comment: I've included that information in the post. Hope some peruvian member answers your question. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The slang ***convi*** is probably short for *[**convidado**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=convidado)*, meaning: someone who is invited to share something, treated to something; or maybe ***convite***, which is a banquet or, by extension, the treat itself.

Based on the above, it makes sense that when someone says *"sin convis"* what they mean is "no invitees" or "no treats", i.e. they do not want to share.